# Inspect faulty AWS EC2 Volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

Recently a site I administer experienced some downtime. When I logged into the machine, I wasn't able to figure out the source of the issue, and so I restored the machine's state by creating a volume based on a previous snapshot, and replacing the machine's faulty root volume with the backup volume.

Now, I'd like to go back and examine the logs and whatnot on the faulty volume, in order to determine the source of the downtime.

When I've attempted to create a new EC2 instance and attach the faulty volume to it, the machine has not been able to start up (1/2 reachability checks failed).

What is the best way for me to recover this faulty volume and inspect its contents?

Thanks!

Comment: Attach it as a *secondary* disk, not the root volume, then mount it.

Answer (score 3):

When EBS volumes are created from snapshots -- including the original AMI snapshots used to launch instances -- they are byte-for-byte identical copies of the volume used to create the snapshot.

That much seems obvious, but an implication is that the UUID of the filesystem on the volume is initially also identical, and may remain so... because creating a new EC2 instance doesn't "install" the OS from distribution media.  It copies an already-completed installation of the OS from the source AMI.

If you have a disk that was formerly a root volume, and attach it to another instance, *and the new instance's root volume has the same AMI ancestry as the secondary disk,* there's a solid chance that the two volumes will have filesystems with the same UUID... and during the startup process, *something* on the system gets disoriented by this fact and actually mounts the secondary volume as `/`.

I don't understand the precise mechanism, but have seen it happen many times.

Boot your new instance first, and *then* attach the volume, then mount it.